# Django IntegrityError SQL: 1048, cannot be null

Tags: python, django, model, integrity

When submitting a form, I receive an `IntegrityError (1048, "Column 'paid_on' cannot be null")`.

After some research I had discovered that many people had solved similar issues by including `null=True, blank=True` in an item's def in models.py, but adding this to my 'paid_on' model has not solved my issue.

Here is the class from my models.py:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
  ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad)
  paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  paid_on = models.DateTimeField('Payment', null=True, blank=True)
  amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
  pricing = models.ForeignKey(Pricing)
  options = models.ManyToManyField(PricingOptions)

  def complete(self, amount=0.0):
    # clear payment
    if self.amount != amount:
        return False

    self.paid = True
    self.paid_on = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.save()

    # update ad
    self.ad.expires_on += datetime.timedelta(days=payment.pricing.length)
    self.ad.created_on = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.ad.active = True
    self.ad.save()
```

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding this to your model won't help as your database still has the restriction. If you want/need to do migrations (you change parts of your models.py and it should change your database) have a look at [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) which supports migrations for Django